A problem on the box topology
Let $S$ be a set and let $\mathbb{R}$ be the real number set with the usual topology.
Define
$$\mathbb{R}^{S}_f=\{t\in \mathbb{R}^S\mid t(s)=0 \mbox{ except for finitely many } s\in S\}. $$
Consider two topologies $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ on the set $\mathbb{R}^{S}_f$. Here
$\mathcal{B}$ is the box topology and $\mathcal{C}$ is the strongest topology on the set such that for each
finite set $S_0$ in $S$, $\mathcal{C}|\mathbb{R}^{S_0}$ is the box topology=product topology, where I regard $\mathbb{R}^{S_0}=\mathbb{R}^{S_0}\times \{0\}^{S\setminus S_0}\subset \mathbb{R}^{S}_f$.
I think $\mathcal{B}\not=\mathcal{C}$ if $S$ is not countable. Am I right?

Do you consider a "stronger" topology to have more open sets, or fewer? (I think there's some ambiguity in the way people use this word. Analysts tend to mean more open sets, I think, but I feel like I've heard it the other way too.)

The topologies are different. See Dugundji's Topology, Appendix I, 4.3: if $S$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ (or larger) then $\mathcal{C}$ is not locally convex. The box topology is generated by products of intervals and hence locally convex.
